# How to store a custom data type in a column in clickhouse?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

For example , I want to create a data type **my_type** which contains two fields name (String) and age (Int) .

I have tried this query , but it is not working .

`CREATE TYPE my_type AS Tuple( name String, age Int32 );`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't supported as syntax or concept in ClickHouse.